# Printing multiple epl labels with a Zebra TLP 2824

Tags: java, zebra-printers, epl

Im trying to print multiple labels in epl code with a Zebra tlp 2824. If I send the code once it prints perfectly but when I loop it a few times it seems to lose the label measures and prints over the edges. Sometimes it adds white labels in between. 
I requested a memory dump which gave me the measures I use in the epl code but this didn't do the job.
Here is the epl code in my java app:

```
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < Controller.codeT.getItems().size(); i++){
    for (int p = 0; p < Integer.valueOf(
               Controller.codeT.getItems().get(i).getQuant()); p++){

            s +=    "N"+"\n"+
                    "q312"+"\n"+
                    "Q199,23"+"\n"+
                    "B55,26,0,1,2,2,152,B,\""+Controller.codeT.getItems()
                                               .get(i).getCode()+"\""+"\n"+
                    "P1,1"+"\n";
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to print the same exact label multiple times, you can modify that EPL Command "P1,1" to "P2,1" which should print the same label twice.  You can reference the EPL manual for this command: https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/eltron/epl2/EPL2_Prog.pdf.

Otherwise, you may need to adjust the label height or label-sense mode.  It sounds like the printer is not auto-detecting the next label start position properly. Unfortunately I'm not as sure how to accomplish this off the top of my head, but the EPL manual I list above will surely tell you.